# How to group with sequence conditions in MySQL or Google Data Studio?

Tags: mysql, database, looker-studio

I have an attendance database where Employee records are stored as below

[image: Database structure]

MySQL version 5.7.26-log (There are no holes in dates, all dates exist but for convenience, I have removed the bulk date data from the insert row statement)

```
CREATE TABLE `stackoverflow` ( `id` int(9) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
                               `Date` date NOT NULL, 
                               `EmpID` varchar(100) NOT NULL, 
                               `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL, 
                               `TeamName` varchar(100) NOT NULL, 
                               `Status` varchar(100) NOT NULL 
                             ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1; 

-- -- Dumping data for table `stackoverflow` -- 
INSERT INTO `stackoverflow` (`id`, `Date`, `EmpID`, `name`, `TeamName`, `Status`) 
VALUES 
(5, '2019-03-01', '303016', 'Yatendra Ranawat', 'Computer Vision', 'P'), 
(23, '2019-03-01', '303128', 'Nikhat Khan', 'Media - 3D Automation', 'P'), 
(193606, '2019-09-02', '303016', 'Yatendra Ranawat', 'Computer Vision', 'P'), 
(194631, '2019-09-03', '303016', 'Yatendra Ranawat', 'Noon', '-'), 
(222309, '2019-09-30', '303016', 'Yatendra Ranawat', 'Noon', '-'), 
(223336, '2019-10-01', '303016', 'Yatendra Ranawat', 'Noon-Indore', 'P'), 
(282742, '2019-11-28', '303016', 'Yatendra Ranawat', 'Noon-Indore', '-'), 
(283765, '2019-11-29', '303016', 'Yatendra Ranawat', 'Home Depot - Indore', 'P'), 
(303251, '2019-12-18', '303128', 'Nikhat Khan', 'Media - 3D Automation', '-'), 
(304275, '2019-12-19', '303128', 'Nikhat Khan', 'US Taxonomy - Indore', 'P'), 
(309393, '2019-12-24', '303128', 'Nikhat Khan', 'US Taxonomy - Indore', 'P'), 
(310416, '2019-12-25', '303128', 'Nikhat Khan', 'Media - 3D Automation', 'PH'), 
(354076, '2020-02-06', '303016', 'Yatendra Ranawat', 'Home Depot - Indore', '-'), 
(354088, '2020-02-06', '303128', 'Nikhat Khan', 'Media - 3D Automation', 'P');
```

I'm using Google Data Studio to create a report for Employee Duration in a team like below

[image: Employee Duration between team-1]

It works perfectly when the employee moves from one team to another and does not return to the teams he previously worked on. But when an employee returns to the team he previously worked on it masses up max and min logic
[image]

What I need to do in MySQL / Google Data Studio to get the result like below with data table like above?

[image: or datastudio]

Let me know if you require any details from my side. Any advise or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: *MySQL version 4.8.5* Even not **5.x**? Really?

Comment: Updated to 5.7.26-log last night

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test also the next variant, it is faster:

```
SELECT EmpID, name, TeamName, startdate, MAX(enddate) enddate
FROM (
SELECT name,
       CASE WHEN EmpId = @id AND TeamName = @team 
            THEN @startdate
            ELSE @startdate := `Date` 
            END startdate,
       `Date` enddate,
       @id := EmpID EmpID,
       @team := TeamName TeamName
FROM stackoverflow, (SELECT @id := '', @team := '', @startdate := '') variables
ORDER BY EmpID, `Date`
) t
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4
ORDER BY 1,2,4,5;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=e0d22a5f9279d4b51a5c87e37c183260)

On my system with hot cache it takes 0.03 sec whereas the queries from previous answer - 25.39 sec and 1 min 54.79 sec respectively. On your system with 220k records the difference must be even more impressive.

Comment: @YatendraRanawat If you use user-defined variables somewhere I'd recommend to rename them in a query and give them long random names (something like `as7bg8lk2df7lki4yt8lv0`) for to avoid any interference with guarantee.

Comment: ... for example use `select concat('@v', md5(current_timestamp));` for names generation...

Answer (score 1):

Test

```
SELECT t4.EmpID, t4.name, t4.TeamName, MIN(t4.startdate) startdate, t4.enddate
FROM ( SELECT t1.EmpID, t1.name, t1.TeamName, t1.`Date` startdate, MAX(t2.`Date`) enddate
       FROM stackoverflow t1
       JOIN stackoverflow t2 ON t1.EmpID = t2.EmpID
                            AND t1.TeamName = t2.TeamName
                            AND t1.`Date` < t2.`Date`
       LEFT JOIN stackoverflow t3 ON t1.EmpID = t3.EmpID
                                 AND t1.TeamName != t3.TeamName
                                 AND t1.`Date` < t3.`Date`                          
                                 AND t3.`Date` < t2.`Date`
       WHERE t3.EmpId IS NULL
       GROUP BY 1,2,3,4 ) t4
GROUP BY 1,2,3,5
ORDER BY 1,2,4,5;
```

---

> = this query is too slow :( Server crashes while running on a table containing 222839 rows – Yatendra Ranawat
>
> = @YatendraRanawat Convert LEFT JOIN into NOT EXISTS... – Akina

```
SELECT t4.EmpID, t4.name, t4.TeamName, MIN(t4.startdate) startdate, t4.enddate
FROM ( SELECT t1.EmpID, t1.name, t1.TeamName, t1.`Date` startdate, MAX(t2.`Date`) enddate
       FROM stackoverflow t1
       JOIN stackoverflow t2 ON t1.EmpID = t2.EmpID
                            AND t1.TeamName = t2.TeamName
                            AND t1.`Date` < t2.`Date`
       WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                          FROM stackoverflow t3 
                          WHERE t1.EmpID = t3.EmpID
                            AND t1.TeamName != t3.TeamName
                            AND t1.`Date` < t3.`Date`                          
                            AND t3.`Date` < t2.`Date` )
       GROUP BY 1,2,3,4 ) t4
GROUP BY 1,2,3,5
ORDER BY 1,2,4,5;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=7c2a02d9b9c243e17c57f7bf1f88396f)

Comment: Working on the demo table but not on the original table as I mentioned "There are no holes in dates, all dates exist but for convenience, I have removed the bulk date data from the insert row statement" you can see complete dataset here https://pastebin.com/7ZnfjX82

Comment: this query is too slow :( Server crashes while running on a table containing 222839 rows

Comment: How? is it same as you did in previous answer?

Comment: @YatendraRanawat Updated, check.

Comment: @YatendraRanawat `CREATE INDEX idx1 ON stackoverflow (EmpID, TeamName, Date);` and `CREATE INDEX idx2 ON stackoverflow (EmpID, Date);` will help.

Comment: I have tried with indexing the table the Query took almost 15 seconds to come up with a result on 700 rows table, as per my calculation answered query will take (222839/700*15/60) 79.6 hours on 222839 rows table. however, the solution Akina provides works and this is why I'm accepting it as an answer. 
http://timetracker.iksulalive.com/screenshot/98fe7fd3ed91566b679ec0f2f1421f6c.webp